# Image preprocessing in Python for OCR

Tags: python-3.x, ocr

I'm doing pre-processing of images for OCR in python. I converted the pdf to binary images. The output I get is like this

[image: Binary image]

I want the ouput to be something like this

[image: desired output]

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: use edge detectors like canny.

Comment: I tried canny. Didn't work

Answer (score -3):

You have to use Tesseract library for extracting text from given image.

I am using window system so I downloaded it from location https://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr-alt/files/.

Suppose you have installed it at location "E:\w\Tesseract-OCR"

Then put your image at the same location. Lets call your image question.png
Now go to command prompt and give command,

E:\w\Tesseract-OCR>tesseract.exe question.png answer.txt

Where answer.txt is text file which Tesseract will create you can give any other name instead of answer.txt and question.txt is your file.

Once command is successfully executed check output in answer.txt.

In case of your image I got following output.

Investment Type: Customer Owned

System Information

Fire III
Video I]

So in this case it is recognizing only text correctly.